# Folder permissions, owner/groups

Tags: files

I am using the [FileField Sources](https://www.drupal.org/project/filefield_sources) module

One of the features is that it allows you to transfer images from a URL to your drupal folder directly, instead of having to save the image on your computer and then selecting it for upload.

The problem I am having is that it won't let me transfer the file.

> http://anywebsite.com/picture.jpg could not be copied, because the
>   destination directory is not properly configured. The folder
>   permission is set to 775, as it should be.

I think it has something to do with the Owner/Group of Ubuntu.

Comment: Did you visit admin/config/media/file-system and confirm that everything is fine?

Comment: Are you aware that this question does not contain an actual question (something that ends with a "?" ...)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In such cases, Drupal first downloads the image to the temporary directory and then moves it to the public directory. Go to admin/config/media/file-system. Make sure that both temporary and public directories are defined and both are writeable by the web server. The easiest way to do this is to make the web server user the owner of the directory. The command is:

```
sudo chown -R www-data <directory>
```

where www-data is the web server user. Depending on your OS and web server, the user could be apache2 or httpd as well.

Comment: ok so I did a `sudo chown -R www-data sites` but I am still getting this error see picture -> `http://s28.postimg.org/i82q1mgzg/problem.jpg` even though my images folder has `drwxrwxr-x  2 www-data www-data images`

Comment: I am guessing the web server user is not "www-data". Can you paste the output of command "ps aux"?

Comment: I got it to work :)